# Why does "print ('\033[0m')" barf on Python 2.7.6 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: python-2.7

When printing nothing but

```
print ('\033[0m')
```

the system exits without any warning. I.e. '\033[0m' must follow a newline in the passed string, or be printed by itself.

I am using the print function so have included;

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Looking at the web help;
https://docs.python.org/release/2.7.6/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print

it does not indicate any exceptions thrown for this function (I am assuming this is the function and not statement documentation).

My question is why does this barf when passed this line and is there a later fix for it?

Thanks.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `from __future__ import print_function;print ('\033[0m')` causes no issue on 2.7.10 or 2.7.7 for me (I do not have 2.7.6 within reach).

Comment: Are you running this in the interactive interpreter or from a script?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Ubuntu 14.04, x64, Python 2.7.6.  Can you give a complete example?

Comment: It's an existing project, several files including other local and system files.

I noticed the problem when a logger someone wrote had strange behaviour and narrowed it down to this. I isolated the problem to the above and can reproduce every time no matter where it appears in the file.

The effect is that following prints do not appear, execution exits with no stack trace but some cleanup.

I think we are running 3.13.n.n. (uname -r), but I am not at work now so can't be precise. Sorry can't give concrete examples other than above. I will play about some more and report back.